# Error compilation React "Module not found: Error: Cannot find file:"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I pulled the repository through github, and when I ran it, it gave dozens of errors similar to the one from ERROR in ./src/Pages/AdminPanel.jsx 8:0-57

Module not found: Error: Cannot find file: 'Agenda.jsx' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\components\AgendaCultural\Components'.

AdminPanel.jsx

````
 * 
 * Componente: Agenda Cultural > Tabela
 * 
 * 
 */

import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TablePagination from '@mui/material/TablePagination';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/SearchBar';
import TableLabels from "../Table/TableLabels.jsx";
import AgendaData from './AgendaData';


/*
* Esta funcao serve cara criar dados em forma organizada
* Para ser usada no componente Table
*/

function createData(Id,Nome, Data, Inicio, Entrada, Local){
  return { Id,Nome, Data,Inicio, Entrada, Local};
}

/*****
 * Dados amostrais, para fins de teste
 * 
 * Usando a funcao createData para gerar dados
 */

const Rows = [
  createData(1, "Luzes da torre", "23/07/2021", "20:00h", "$9", "Torre Eiffel-Paris"),
  createData(2, "Luzes da torre", "23/07/2021", "20:00h", "$9", "Torre Eiffel-Paris"),
  createData(3, "Luzes da torre", "23/07/2021", "20:00h", "$9", "Torre Eiffel-Paris"),
  createData(4, "Luzes da torre", "23/07/2021", "20:00h", "$9", "Torre Eiffel-Paris"),
  createData(5, "Luzes da torre", "23/07/2021", "20:00h", "$9", "Torre Eiffel-Paris"),
  createData(6, "Luzes da torre", "23/07/2021", "20:00h", "$9", "Torre Eiffel-Paris"),
  createData(7, "Luzes da torre", "23/07/2021", "20:00h", "$9", "Torre Eiffel-Paris"),
  createData(8, "Luzes da torre", "23/07/2021", "20:00h", "$9", "Torre Eiffel-Paris"),

];


/**
 * Labels para cada coluna da tabela
 */

const Columns = [
    {id : 1, label : "Nome", align : "left"},
    {id : 2, label : "Data", align : "left"},
    {id : 3, label : "Inicio", align : "left"},
    {id : 4, label : "Entrada", align : "left"},
    {id : 5, label : "Local", align : "right"},
    {id : 6, label : "Editar", align : "right"},
    {id : 7, label : "Excluir", align : "right"}
]


function Agenda() {

  /**
  * State para controlar a paginação da tabela
  */
  
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);
 
  const handleChangePage = (_event, newPage) => {
     setPage(newPage);
  };
    
   /**
    * Esta funcao serve para trocar de pagina ao clickar o botao de next
    */
   const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
     setRowsPerPage(+event.target.value);
     setPage(0);
   };
 
 
   /***
    * Este state serve para pegar o estado da Busca
    */
   const [query,setQuery] = useState("");
   function SearchTable (search) {
     setQuery(search)
   }
 
   /****
    * Estas variaveis serve para  Agroupar(Collecionar) dados 
    * Que enviarmos na Tabela
    */
   const allData = [page,rowsPerPage,query,Columns]; 
   const TableTitle = "Agenda Cultural";


  return (

    <div className='pt-10'>
      
      <Paper sx={{ width: '100%', overflow: 'hidden', borderRadius : '20px'}} className = "p-4">
        <TableContainer sx={{ maxHeight: 440 }}>
          <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
            <TableHead>

              {
                /*
                * Tabela de labels 
                */ 
              }
              <TableRow>
                
                  <TableCell 
                  colSpan={2}
                  style={{
                  border : "none",
                  fontSize : "1.8rem",
                  fontWeight : "bold",
                  paddingBottom : "0px"
                  
                }
              }>
                
                    {TableTitle}
                  
                  </TableCell>
              </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
              
                  {
                  
                  /*
                  * Componente de consulta 
                  */ 
                  
                  
              }

                <TableCell align="center" colSpan={2}>   
                    <SearchBar handleQuery={SearchTable}/>
                </TableCell>

                {
                /*
                * Componente de labels
                */
                }

                <TableCell align="center" colSpan={3}>
                  <TablePagination
                      rowsPerPageOptions={[5,10, 25, 100]}
                      component="div"
                      count={Rows.length}
                      rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                      page={page}
                      onPageChange={handleChangePage}
                      onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                      className = "bg-white"
                      labelRowsPerPage = "Monstrar"
                      sx = {{'& .MuiTablePagination-actions .MuiTablePagination-displayedRows' : { display : 'none'}}}
                  />
                </TableCell>

                {
                /***
                 * Componente botão para adicionar novo evento
                */
                }
                
                <TableCell
                  sx = {{
                    display : "flex",
                    justifyContent : "right"
                  }}
                >
                  <a href = "/admin/agenda" className='bg-cyan-800 text-white px-12 py-4 rounded-full hover:bg-cyan-600'>Cadastrar novo</a>
                </TableCell>
                
            </TableRow>

            {
              /*
               * Componente para criar as labels
               * 
               */
            }
            <TableRow>
              <TableLabels data={Columns}/>
            </TableRow>

            </TableHead>          
            
            <TableBody>            
              {
                /*
                * Componente para criar e renderizar as linhas da tabela
                */
                <AgendaData data = {Rows} other={[...allData]}/>

              } 
            </TableBody>
          
          </Table>

        </TableContainer>

            {
              /*
               * Componente responsável pela paginação da tabela
               * `ver outros dados` 
               */
            }

            <TablePagination
              rowsPerPageOptions={[5,10, 25, 100]}
              component="div"
              count={Rows.length}
              rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
              page={page}
              onPageChange={handleChangePage}
              onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
              className = "bg-white"
              labelRowsPerPage = {false}
              sx = {
                {

                  '& .MuiTablePagination-select, &.MuiSelect-nativeInput,& .css-yf8vq0-MuiSelect-nativeInput, & .css-pqjvzy-MuiSvgIcon-root-MuiSelect-icon ' : {
                    display : "none"
                  },
                  
                  '& .MuiTablePagination-displayedRows' : {
                    display : "block"
                  },

                  '& .css-8t3sgi-MuiTablePagination-root, & .MuiTablePagination-displayedRows' : {
                    display : "none"
                  },
                  '& .css-zylse7-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root, &.Mui-disabled' : {
                    border : "1px solid #155e75",
                    padding : "0px",
                    margin : "10px",

                    '& :hover' : {
                      backgroundColor : "red"
                    }
                  }
                }

              }
            />
    
    </Paper>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Agenda; ```
````

Comment: Well... do you have a file called 'AgendaData.jsx' in 'src\components\AgendaCultural\Components'?

Comment: No, I don't know where he's taking it from in /Components that's showing up at the end, I'm trying to find it.